# How to obtain raw View result for Drupal 5?

Tags: views, 5

How do I get a raw result from a view similar to this $view->result for Drupal 5 ? I would like to get results from the database and run calculations before displaying to the user. I really need to gain access to the the raw data before it's themed by the Drupal engine.

Comment: By get access you mean outputting them, or altering them in the normal course of rendering? Please clarify a bit if you expect focused answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in here somewhere but I have no way to test it out.

Check out [Intro to Views 1](https://drupal.org/node/54432) and especially [Inserting Views](https://drupal.org/node/48816) where the [views_build_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_build_view/5) function is discussed.  From the discussion there, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$view = views_get_view('your_view');
$results = views_build_view('items', $view);
```

with `$results` now being "An array of objects containing the results of the query."

Now how you theme this is up to you to decipher :)